# Custom Tokens TOKEN_REGISTER not getting invoked

Tags: tokens

CiviCRM 5.9.1
Drupal 7.61

Trying to create custom tokens using "hook_civicrm_container", TOKEN_REGISTER is getting set as well as TOKEN_EVALUATE function in $container variable but TOKEN_REGISTER function is never getting invoked. Testing through opening up 'Send en Email' action on contact record.

Below is the code in place in a custom module.

```
function test_module_civicrm_container($container) {

  $container->addResource(new FileResource(FILE));
  $container->findDefinition('dispatcher')->addMethodCall('addListener',
    array(\Civi\Token\Events::TOKEN_REGISTER, '_register_tokens')
  );
  $container->findDefinition('dispatcher')->addMethodCall('addListener',
    array(\Civi\Token\Events::TOKEN_EVALUATE, '_evaluate_tokens')
  );
  //CRM_Core_Error::debug('container', $container);exit;
}

function _register_tokens(\Civi\Token\Event\TokenRegisterEvent $e) {
echo 'came here';exit;
  $e->entity('profile')
    ->register('viewUrl', ts('Profile View URL'))
    ->register('viewLink', ts('Profile View Link'));
}

function _evaluate_tokens(\Civi\Token\Event\TokenValueEvent $e) {
  foreach ($e->getRows() as $row) {
    // @var TokenRow $row 
    $row->format('text/html');
    $row->tokens('profile', 'viewUrl', 'http://example.com/profile/' . $row->context['contactId']);
    $row->tokens('profile', 'viewLink', ts("<a href='%1'>Open Profile</a>", array(
      1 => $row->tokens['profile']['viewUrl'],
    )));
  }
}
```

Trying to follow [doc here](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/token/#token-events-v47)